# Can't connect to the Internet, but can to a router

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and see a question mark in place of wireless symbol in the top main bar. I can't connect to the Internet, however, I can connect to my router. Internet connection on my Windows notebook works fine.

I've tried:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Here's lshw:

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:c1:3b:29
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f253b000-f253bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: a4:4e:31:48:ff:18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:32 memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwp0s20u4i6
       serial: ae:99:db:a9:c7:96
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

Any help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're not getting the default gateway set to your router. Try looking at the output of `route -n` and see what's listed for the destination `0.0.0.0`.

It's also possible that you're not getting DNS. You might try to do an `nslookup` on some known URL to see if you get anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not installed net-tools, but for nslookup www.google.com it returns "connection timed out; no servers could be reached".